# Cannot download Chrome and other app on MacBook Air purchased in Thailand

Tags: macbook-pro, ventura

Why am I seeing a message that Chrome and other important app is restricted in my region? I have changed my location already from Asia to Canada.

Comment: Which location setting did you change?

Comment: Is the problem that your AppleID's address is in one country, and you are trying to access the Mac App Store of another country?